# Multi filter list doesn't combine 2 objects

Tags: jquery, html

So i'm trying to make a filter function in jquery. But i can't get it to work properly.
So this is what i'm trying to do

1. I have a HTML List
2. I have an Input
3. This input filters the list real-time (on keyup filters the list)
4. When the button add is click the current filter should be saved
5. These saved filters act as an OR filter, so it filters everything out that is not in the list or the input

[FIDDLE FOR FANS](http://jsfiddle.net/S9NzU/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="filter">
    <div id="filters"></div>
    <input id="search" type="text" value="" /> <a id="addFilter">ADD</a>

</div>
<ul>
    <li class="log">Test 1</li>
    <li class="log">Test 2</li>
    <li class="log">Test 3</li>
    <li class="log">Bla 1</li>
    <li class="log">Blab 2</li>
    <li class="log">Siawq 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
//case insencitive :contains()
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
    return function (elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

//OnClick of add button, add filter to list, clear field
$("#addFilter").click(function () {
    if($('input#search').val() != ""){
        //filters.push();
        $("#filters").append("<div>"+$('input#search').val()+"</div>");
        $('input#search').val("");
    }
});

//On Click of filter list item to remove filter
$("#filters").on('click',"div",function() {    
    $(this).remove();
    $("input#search").change();
});

//Filter event on change and keyup
$("input#search").change(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if (filter) {
        var matches = $("ul").find('li.log:Contains(' + filter + ')');

        var obj = $('#filters > div');
        var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
        for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var add = $("ul").find('li.log:Contains(' + arr[i].innerText + ')');
            matches = $.extend(matches,add);
        }
        $("li.log").not(matches).slideUp();
        matches.slideDown();
    } else {
        $("ul").find("li.log").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
})
    .keyup(function () {
    $(this).change();
});
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: The added filters don't work properly, what i've tried to do is call the filters from the divs then loop through them and put them all in 1 object. That part doesn't work correctly. It results in the latest object to be only filtered.

Comment: So if I type "a", click Add and then type "t" and click Add, I should end up with the *entire* list because "a" or "t" is present in each list item?

Comment: @dnagirl indeed, it shows all list items that contain one of the added filters, including what is typed into the input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok another hour of fiddling and i've found my answer.

[FIDDLE FOR FANS](http://jsfiddle.net/Burnacid/hHAbK/1/)

```
if (filter) {
        var matches = $("ul").find('li.log:Contains(' + filter + ')');

        var obj = $('#filters > div');
        var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
        for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var add = $("ul").find('li.log:Contains(' + arr[i].innerText + ')');
            matches = $.extend(matches,add);
        }
        $("li.log").not(matches).slideUp();
        matches.slideDown();
}
```

Should be:

```
if (filter || arr.length != 0) {
    if (filter) {
        var matches = $("ul").find('li.log:Contains(' + filter + ')');
    } else {
        var matches = $();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        matches = matches.add('ul li.log:Contains(' + arr[i].innerText + ')');
    }
    $("li.log").not(matches).slideUp();
    matches.slideDown();
}
```